# Scheme excersize

Tags: scheme, racket

```
(define (weights# mobile)
  (cond ((= (is-sculpture? mobile) #t) 1)
((= (and (= (is-sculpture? mobile) #f) (= (is-sculpture? (right-mobile mobile)) #t) (= (is-sculpture? (left-mobile mobile)) #t)) #t) 3)
(else (+ 3 (- (weights# (right-mobile mobile)) 1) (- (weights# (left-mobile mobile)) 1))))
  )
```

`is-sculpture` is a function that returns `#t` or `#f`. I have set the code to return a number, depending on the code but this message is appearing to my screen.

```
> contract violation
  expected: number?
  given: #f
  argument position: 1st
  other arguments...:
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. According to your own text *`is-sculpture` is a function that returns `#t` or `#f`*. `=` is a function that takes only numeric arguments, thus this call should go wrong:

```
(= (is-sculpture? (right-mobile mobile)) #t) ; #t is not a number
```

Now to check one value against another you can use `eq?` for the exact same object (`#t` is the same object every time, symbols too), `eqv?` for primitive types.. `(eq? 5 5) ; ==> #f` while `(eqv? 5 5) ; ==> #t`. `equal?` also include sequences of same type where all primitives are `eqv?`. eg. `(eqv? (list 1 2 3) (list 1 2 3)) ; ==> #f` while `(equal? (list 1 2 3) (list 1 2 3)) ; ==> #t`.

For things that returns `#t` or `#f` you don't need to `(eq? (is-sculpture? ...) #t)` because it is the same as `(is-sculpture? ...)`. To check the oposite you just wrap the result in `not`, thus `(not (is-sculpture? ...))` becomes `#t` for `#f` result.

In the second term in your `cond` you know `(is-sculpture? mobile)` wasn't true so why do you check if it's false when it only can be false in the next line? Every term in `cond` you can expect all the previous terms in the same `cond` to be false.

We don't actually parse code with our eyes so the identation tells us how many parens there are and not the actuall amount of parens. Thus badly formatted lisp code is unreadable.

In Racket you need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> it will reident your code. You desperately need it. Also put all the ending parens at the end of the previous line. Heres how I would format it:

```
(define (weights# mobile)
  (cond ((is-sculpture? mobile)
         1)
        ; (is-sculpture? mobile) is #f
        ((and (is-sculpture? (right-mobile mobile))
              (is-sculpture? (left-mobile mobile)))
         3)
        ; At least one of the other is-sculpture? expressions are false.
        (else
         (+ 1 ; 3 + x-1 + y-2 == 1+x+y
            (weights# (right-mobile mobile))
            (weights# (left-mobile mobile))))))
```

Besides removnig all the `=` tests that are reduncant I haven't changed the logic and I have no way of testing since I don't have your other functions or what arguments this takes.